# How do we know if payment is successful or not in Indian Ccavenue Payment gateway

Tags: php, payment-gateway, ccavenue

i have integrated the CcAvenue payment gatewaymethod in my website along with the citrus payment gateway. There is a redirect url option in CCavenue method so whenever a user cancelled or  paid the amount then it is redirecting them to the redirect url. So my client wants that whenever someone cancelled or paid the amount then on the redirecting page it will show them the status that your transaction has failed or successfull and also it will show them the details on that redirect page. In citrus payment method, they have given the option but in CCavenue, i dont know about it. IS there any kinds of code which will helps me to solve out my problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am able to solve it using

`if($Checksum=="true" && $AuthDesc=="Y") 
    // This will be shown for the successfull transaction`

For more info visit the below url link:-

http://subversion.assembla.com/svn/katalog/trunk/html/scripts/modules/payment/class.ccavenue.php

Comment: Could you please explain in detail? I need a working REST API for this.